# How would I use Pythons thread class to sync operations across threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I was just reading through the threading API in Python 3 and I don't see a method of syncing threads.  In my case I'm creating performance testing in a Server and Client environment so I might want to use the thread class call this test with N users:

```
def tDoTest( ):
    doSync()   # Wait for all thread creation
    doLogin()
    doSync()   # Wait for all users to login
    startTest()
    create100Rows()
    endTest()
    doSync()   # Wait for completion
    doLogout()
```

I was hoping there was a built in way to handle this that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [blocking queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

```py
import queue

q = queue.Queue()
```

If you want one thread to wait for all members of a group of three other threads to do some task, the waiting thread could `get()` three tokens from the queue:

```py
for i in range(3):
    q.get()
```

Each of the three awaited threads could signify that it has completed its task by putting an informationless token into the queue:

```py
q.put(())
```

The waiting thread will not exit its `for` loop until it has collected all three tokens.

---

You could wrap it up in a class:

```py
import queue
import threading
import time

class CountdownLatch:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.q = queue.Queue()

    def check_in(self):
        self.q.put(())

    def await_all_checkins(self):
        for i in range(self.N):
            self.q.get()

def demo_CountDownLatch():
    cdl = CountdownLatch(3)
    def task(cdl,delay):
        time.sleep(delay)
        print(delay)
        cdl.check_in()

    threading.Thread(target=task, args=(cdl,2.0)).start()
    threading.Thread(target=task, args=(cdl,1.5)).start()
    threading.Thread(target=task, args=(cdl,1.0)).start()
    cdl.await_all_checkins()
    print("nighty night.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo_CountDownLatch()
```

Comment: Perfect, TY... if I understand this I'll add my sync function to MY thread class create the Queue call put on it and then wait using the for statement.  Usually that syntax would only do the loop the specified times.  So a bit worried about late comers.  I'll need to substitute the hard coded 3 with something that gets the intended thread count.  I allow the CLI to indicate the 'user' count.

Comment: I need to reuse the Sync method so maybe need to reset queue?  Oh and maybe I wasn't clear enough?  I need to do this within the thread.  I did state that tDoTest() was called by the thread class.

Comment: @Keith, I'm not sure what you're asking, but if _any_ thread calls `cdl.await_all_checkins()`, then it will be forced to wait until `N` calls to `check_in()` have been performed by other threads.

Comment: your code seams to be a one time usage.  I've rewrote your code to show the issue.  Unfortunately this causes a pause that lasts forever.  I'll show it below.

Comment: @Keith, Maybe I misunderstood your need. I thought you only wanted one thread to wait until the other three had completed their tasks. If you want _all_ of the threads to wait until they are _all_ ready to go on to the next step, then you probably need a [`Barrier`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects).

Comment: TY the barrier worked perfectly.  I'm doing performance timing so I want to be sure that all threads have the same weight.  Otherwise some threads would finish early.

Answer (score 0):

OK after a bunch of searching this is the answer.  Never expected this functionality to be named Barrier(). The is a built in function for it.

```
b = Barrier(2, timeout=5)

def doSync():
    ct  = threading.currentThread()
    b.wait( )
    print('Sync done: ' + ct.getName())
```

The output looks like as expected now:

```
0.75
1.0
Sync done: 1
Sync done: 2
0.75
1.0
Sync done: 1
Sync done: 2
0.75
1.0
Sync done: 1
Sync done: 2
```